# Drop table if it's empty / pass the result of count(*) to variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I would like to check if a table is empty, and if it is, I would like drop it. I know this little function doesn't seem as a useful thing by itself, but I have a much longer function, so this is just the main part.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.cl_tbl(t_name character varying)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    rownum int;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rownum FROM format('myschema.%I',t_name);
    IF rownum = 0 then
        EXECUTE format('DROP TABLE myschema.%I',t_name);
    END IF;
    RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

My problem is, that the line

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rownum FROM format('myschema.%I',t_name);
```

doesn't returns 0 if the table is empty, instead it returns 1 as the number of rows of the selection.

```
    | count(bigint)
--------------------
 1  |       0
```

I've tried this as well:

```
rownum := SELECT COUNT(*) FROM format('myschema.%I',t_name);
```

but the result is the same. How could I pass the real number of the rows of a given table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using EXECUTE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.cl_tbl(t_name character varying)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    rownum int;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('select count(*) from %I', t_name) into rownum;
    IF rownum = 0 then
        EXECUTE format('DROP TABLE %I',t_name);
    END IF;
    RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [EXISTS()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-subquery.html)  - `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table_name)`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.cl_tbl(t_name character varying)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    x BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('select exists (select * from myschema.%I) t', t_name) INTO x;
    IF x = False then
        EXECUTE format('DROP TABLE myschema.%I',t_name);
    END IF;
    RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: Thank you! I see what's happening here, but for some reason it doesn't do the job. I checked and the result of `SELECT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM format('myschema.%I',t_name))` is False, so I don't know what's the poblem.

Comment: You need to make the whole exists query dynamic: `execute format('select exists (select * from %I) t', t_name) into x;`